# When value in dropdownlist have ever been selected will not display

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii, yii2

I have two tables that relate to each other one to one that is Husband and Wife. I've made my value dropdownlist and to get the data from the table Husband. I want when its value had been chosen will not appear on his dropdownlist. Perhaps there are other references or can be helped. For the code can be seen in the image below.

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\Husband;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Wife */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="wife-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'id_husband')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Husband::find()->where('status' => 0)->all(), 'id_husband', 'name'),
        ['prompt' => 'Pilih']    
    ) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'status')->dropDownList(['0' => 'Tidak Aktif', '1' => 'Aktif'],
    ['prompt'=>'--Pilih--', 'style' => 'width:380px']) ?> 

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention as array in the where condition .

Use `->where(['status' => 0])" instead of "->where('status' => 0)`

So it is:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'id_husband')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Husband::find()->where(['status' => 0])->all(), 'id_husband', 'name'),
        ['prompt' => 'Pilih']    
    ) ?>
```

Comment: The result is error. Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'status' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `husband` WHERE `status`=0. For column "status" any in table wife, not husband.

Comment: Do you have status column in husband table?

Comment: may i know what are the columns in husband table and as well as for wife?

Comment: In husband table not have status column @satya

Comment: Then Please try "Husband::findAll()"

Comment: For table husband : id_husband, name. Primary key is id_husband. For table wife : id_husband, name, status. Primary key is id_husband

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126197/discussion-between-nur-chalik-azhar-and-satya).